# VAE latent variables apper highly correlated

Tags: autoencoders

I am attempting to train a Beta-VAE on historical interest rate curves to map interest rate curves to a lower dimension latent space. I have chosen to use VAE over PCA or autoencoders because I want a regularized latent space to make a generative process possible (continuity and completeness)

The problem I have is that the encoded latent space my model produces shows highly correlated latent variables. In the first plot below, I have chose to find a latent space of dimension n=2, and after training, I extract the latent space as the encoded mus (means). You can clearly see the high degree of correlation, suggesting that this latent space is far from independent.

[image: Encoded Latent Variables - Deterministic]

However, in the training process, we sample the latent space through the reparameterization trick. These sampled latent variables are what drives the loss functions, including KLD. If I extract "sampled" latent variables from the trained model using the forward pass (that is, I introduce the sampling noise), my latent variables (now sampled form respective mu and logvar) now appear as two independent Gaussian variables (second figure)

[image: Encoded Latent Variables - with sampling]

So it seems during training that the model is doing what it is supposed to do, but ultimately leaving me with a deterministic mapping (the encoded mu) that does not have the desired regularization.

I am asking for any insights on this phenomenon and potential solutions or alternatives. I want to find a deterministic mapping of my original dataset to a regularized latent space. My understanding is that the sampling step in VAE plays a big part in that regularization, forcing the latent space towards one that has the desirable properties of continuity and completeness. I have tried training with varying choices of Beta hyperparameter and network architecture, but results always follow the same pattern.